# Attempting to Strike Out Li Element in React Using .strike()

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use the index returned from DisplayTasks component to access the list string in the DOM (which looks successful from my console logs), then strike the string out on click. The problem is it doesn't actually strike the string out on click despite console.log telling me it's putting strike tags around it. Not sure why?

strikeTask method in App.js

```
 strikeTask = index => {
    const string = document.getElementById(index).childNodes[1].data
    string.strike()
  }
```

Display Tasks Component:

```
import React from 'react';

const DisplayTasks = ({ tasks, removeTask, strikeTask }) => { 
  return (
    <ol> 
      {tasks.map((task, index) => 
        <li key={index} id={index} onClick={() => strikeTask(index) }> {task} 
        <button style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }} onClick={() => removeTask(index) }>Remove</button>
        </li>)}
    </ol>
    )
}

export default DisplayTasks;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

/* InputTaskForm renders a form, and returns the input to our storeTask method. */
const InputTaskForm = ({ task }) => {
  return (
    <form name="charlie" onSubmit={task}>
      <input name="userinput" type="text" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

const DisplayTasks = ({ tasks, removeTask, strikeTask }) => {
  return (
    <ol>
      {tasks.map((task, index) => (
        <li key={index} id={index} onClick={() => strikeTask(index)}>
          {" "}
          {task}
          <button
            style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }}
            onClick={() => removeTask(index)}
          >
            Remove
          </button>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ol>
  );
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      userinput: "",
      tasksarray: []
    };
  }

  /* =================================================================================
                                        #METHODS 
   ================================================================================= */

  /* ================================== #STORE TASK ================================== 
    - event.preventDefault(); stops the form from refreshing
    - The setState function updates our states via user input returned from the InputTaskForm 
         component
    - document.forms['charlie'].reset() resets the form after the user submits a task.
   ============================================================================= */
  storeTask = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      userinput: event.target.userinput.value,
      tasksarray: this.state.tasksarray.concat(
        " " + event.target.userinput.value
      )
    });
    document.forms["charlie"].reset();
  };

  /* ================================== #REMOVE TASK ================================== 
    - use the spread operator to copy the state of our tasksarray into a new array.
    - use the index returned from our onClick event to identify which item to remove.
    - remove the item from our new array via splice then replace our old array using setState.
   ============================================================================= */
  removeTask = index => {
    const removedTasksArray = [...this.state.tasksarray];
    removedTasksArray.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({ tasksarray: removedTasksArray });
  };

  /* ============================== #CROSS OUT TASK ============================== 
   ============================================================================= */
  strikeTask = index => {
    const string = document.getElementById(index).childNodes[1].data;
    string.strike();
  };

  /* ================================ #COMPONENTS  ================================ 
  - const { tasksarray } = this.state  is to destructure tasksarray (so we 
     no longer have to prefix this.state to it when we want to use it)
  - InputTaskForm renders a form, and returns the input to our storeTask method.
  - DisplayTasks maps each input in the tasksarray state into an html list.
   ============================================================================= */
  render() {
    const { tasksarray } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <InputTaskForm task={this.storeTask} />
        <DisplayTasks
          tasks={tasksarray}
          removeTask={this.removeTask}
          strikeTask={this.strikeTask}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your tasks as objects like `[{ title: 'some title', strike: false }]`, on click the title set strike to true. Don't modify dom elements directly use state to manage the dom.

**Option 1:**

```
storeTask = event => {

event.preventDefault();
  this.setState({
    userinput: event.target.userinput.value,
    tasksarray: [
      ...this.state.tasksarray,
      { title: event.target.userinput.value, strike: false }
    ]
  });
  document.forms["charlie"].reset();
};
```

strike task function, set strike property to true | false.

```
strikeTask = index => {
  const selected = this.state.tasksarray[index];

  this.setState({
    tasksarray: [
      ...this.state.tasksarray.slice(0, index),
      Object.assign({}, this.state.tasksarray[index], {
        title: selected.title,
        strike: !selected.strike
      }),
      ...this.state.tasksarray.slice(index + 1)
    ]
  });
};
```

In your display task component check if strike is true. if true surround text with `<strike>` tag

```
const DisplayTasks = ({ tasks, removeTask, strikeTask }) => {
  return (
    <ol>
      {tasks.map((task, index) => (
        <li key={index} id={index} onClick={() => strikeTask(index)}>
          {" "}
          {task.strike ? <strike>{task.title}</strike> : task.title}
          <button
            style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }}
            onClick={e => removeTask(e, index)}
          >
            Remove
          </button>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ol>
  );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

const InputTaskForm = ({ task }) => {
  return (
    <form name="charlie" onSubmit={task}>
      <input name="userinput" type="text" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

const DisplayTasks = ({ tasks, removeTask, strikeTask }) => {
  return (
    <ol>
      {tasks.map((task, index) => (
        <li key={index} id={index} onClick={() => strikeTask(index)}>
          {" "}
          {task.strike ? <strike>{task.title}</strike> : task.title}
          <button
            style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }}
            onClick={e => removeTask(e, index)}
          >
            Remove
          </button>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ol>
  );
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      userinput: "",
      tasksarray: []
    };
  }

  /* =================================================================================
                                      #METHODS 
   ================================================================================= */

  /* ================================== #STORE TASK ================================== 
    - event.preventDefault(); stops the form from refreshing
    - The setState function updates our states via user input returned from the InputTaskForm 
         component
    - document.forms['charlie'].reset() resets the form after the user submits a task.
   ============================================================================= */
  storeTask = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      userinput: event.target.userinput.value,
      tasksarray: [
        ...this.state.tasksarray,
        { title: event.target.userinput.value, strike: false }
      ]
    });
    document.forms["charlie"].reset();
  };

  /* ================================== #REMOVE TASK ================================== 
    - use the spread operator to copy the state of our tasksarray into a new array.
    - use the index returned from our onClick event to identify which item to remove.
    - remove the item from our new array via splice then replace our old array using setState.
   ============================================================================= */
  removeTask = (e, index) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    const removedTasksArray = [...this.state.tasksarray];
    removedTasksArray.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({ tasksarray: removedTasksArray });
  };

  /* ============================== #CROSS OUT TASK ============================== 
   ============================================================================= */
  strikeTask = index => {
    const selected = this.state.tasksarray[index];

    this.setState({
      tasksarray: [
        ...this.state.tasksarray.slice(0, index),
        Object.assign({}, this.state.tasksarray[index], {
          title: selected.title,
          strike: !selected.strike
        }),
        ...this.state.tasksarray.slice(index + 1)
      ]
    });
  };

  // strikeTask = index => {
  //   var x = document.getElementById(index);
  //   if (x.style.display === "none") {
  //     x.style.display = "block";
  //   } else {
  //     x.style.display = "none";
  //   }
  // }

  /* ================================ #COMPONENTS  ================================ 
  - const { tasksarray } = this.state  is to destructure tasksarray (so we 
     no longer have to prefix this.state to it when we want to use it)
  - InputTaskForm renders a form, and returns the input to our storeTask method.
  - DisplayTasks maps each input in the tasksarray state into an html list.
   ============================================================================= */
  render() {
    const { tasksarray } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <InputTaskForm task={this.storeTask} />
        <DisplayTasks
          tasks={tasksarray}
          removeTask={this.removeTask}
          strikeTask={this.strikeTask}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
```

**Option 2:**

create a TodoItem component, each component manages it's strike through behaviour.

```
class TodoItem extends React.Component {
  state = {
    strike: false
  }

  strikeTask = () => {
    this.setState({
      strike: !this.state.strike
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { strike } = this.state;
    return (
      <li onClick={this.strikeTask}>
        {" "}
        {strike ? <strike>{this.props.text}</strike> : this.props.text}
        <button
          style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }}
          onClick={this.props.removeTask}
        >
          Remove
          </button>
      </li>
    )
  }
}
```

Then use it

```
const DisplayTasks = ({ tasks, removeTask, strikeTask }) => {
  return (
    <ol>
      {tasks.map((task, index) => (
      <TodoItem text={task} removeTask={() => removeTask(index)} />
      ))}
    </ol>
  );
};
```

```html
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
        <div id="root"></div>

     <script type="text/babel">
        
    class TodoItem extends React.Component {
      state = {
        strike: false
      }

      strikeTask = () => {
        this.setState({
          strike: !this.state.strike
        })
      }

      render() {
        const { strike } = this.state;
        return (
          <li onClick={this.strikeTask}>
            {" "}
            {strike ? <strike>{this.props.text}</strike> : this.props.text}
            <button
              style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }}
              onClick={this.props.removeTask}
            >
              Remove
              </button>
          </li>
        )
      }
    }

        /* InputTaskForm renders a form, and returns the input to our storeTask method. */
        const InputTaskForm = ({ task }) => {
          return (
            <form name="charlie" onSubmit={task}>
              <input name="userinput" type="text" />
              <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
          );
        };

        const DisplayTasks = ({ tasks, removeTask, strikeTask }) => {
          return (
            <ol>
              {tasks.map((task, index) => (
               <TodoItem text={task} removeTask={() => removeTask(index)} />
              ))}
            </ol>
          );
        };

        class App extends React.Component {
          constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
              userinput: "",
              tasksarray: []
            };
          }

          /* =================================================================================
                                                #METHODS 
           ================================================================================= */

          /* ================================== #STORE TASK ================================== 
            - event.preventDefault(); stops the form from refreshing
            - The setState function updates our states via user input returned from the InputTaskForm 
                 component
            - document.forms['charlie'].reset() resets the form after the user submits a task.
           ============================================================================= */
          storeTask = event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.setState({
              userinput: event.target.userinput.value,
              tasksarray: this.state.tasksarray.concat(
                " " + event.target.userinput.value
              )
            });
            document.forms["charlie"].reset();
          };

          /* ================================== #REMOVE TASK ================================== 
            - use the spread operator to copy the state of our tasksarray into a new array.
            - use the index returned from our onClick event to identify which item to remove.
            - remove the item from our new array via splice then replace our old array using setState.
           ============================================================================= */
          removeTask = index => {
            const removedTasksArray = [...this.state.tasksarray];
            removedTasksArray.splice(index, 1);
            this.setState({ tasksarray: removedTasksArray });
          };

          /* ============================== #CROSS OUT TASK ============================== 
           ============================================================================= */
          strikeTask = index => {
            const string = document.getElementById(index).childNodes[1].data;
            string.strike();
          };

          /* ================================ #COMPONENTS  ================================ 
          - const { tasksarray } = this.state  is to destructure tasksarray (so we 
             no longer have to prefix this.state to it when we want to use it)
          - InputTaskForm renders a form, and returns the input to our storeTask method.
          - DisplayTasks maps each input in the tasksarray state into an html list.
           ============================================================================= */
          render() {
            const { tasksarray } = this.state;
            return (
              <div>
                <InputTaskForm task={this.storeTask} />
                <DisplayTasks
                  tasks={tasksarray}
                  removeTask={this.removeTask}
                  strikeTask={this.strikeTask}
                />
              </div>
            );
          }
        }

        ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
        </script>
```

Comment: Yes, I read before that changing the array state to an object and then having the strikethrough set by the state was the proper way. I haven't had time to mess around with it yet but I'll try some more things tomorrow. Even though you didn't give an answer using strike() I appreciate the effort you put into the answer, and I know this is the right/conventional way, so I chose this as the accepted answer.

Comment: the one with object is better, as you can save the data in db or storage, even after the user refreshes the window you'll get which item was striked.

Comment: I've been looking over your code today to understand it better, but find myself confused by the two slice() lines in the strikeTask method. What exactly are those two lines doing? Edit: After thinking about it for a while it seems like they're just there to keep the elements below and above the index from disappearing when we set the new state. Is that right?

Comment: it's to make sure we don't mutate state data, we get the first part of the array in state, and modify the object with object assign and get the last part of the array to make a new array. read further here https://medium.com/@fknussel/arrays-objects-and-mutations-6b23348b54aa

Answer (score 1):

The problem happens because `string.strike()` returns the string you want but it doesn't modify the dom with the new value. You can:

1. Modify the dom directly:

```
strikeTask = index => {
  const string = document.getElementById(index).childNodes[1].data
  document.getElementById(index).innerHTML = string.strike()
}
```

2. Create a component that handles its own `stricken` state and manage your css accordingly (class, css in js, whatever you are using).

```
const Task = ({ task, removeTask, index }) => {
  const [isStricken, setIsStricken] = useState(false)
  return (
    <li
      onClick={() => setIsStricken(true)}
      className={isStricken ? 'stricken' : ''}
    >
      {task} 
      <button
        style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }}
        onClick={() => removeTask(index) }
      >
        Remove
      </button>
    </li>
  )
}
```

This is a more declarative approach (which React encourages) since your component is reacting to a state change instead of manually modifying the dom.

Comment: I'm a little confused why it isn't modifying the dom, is it becuase the JSX isn't re-rendering or is there a more abstract explanation?

Comment: Because all `strike()` does is return a string wrapped in `<strike>` tags, it doesn't change the original node from where you're getting the string. You need to either manually set its value `elem.innerHTML = string.strike()` or use a declarative approach.

Comment: Think about it this way: `document.getElementById(index).childNodes[1].data` gets the current value. `string.strike()` obtains a new value. But you never set the new value into the node to update the old one.